# Mobilefirst Starter Application for Ionic ng-click fires twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

**Environment:**

1. Eclipse 4.4.2,
2. IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1,
3. StarterApplication_ionic-release71.zip,
4. angular-route.js [AngularJS v1.2.12 part of sample application] and
5. ionic.bundle.js [Ionic, v1.0.0-beta.1 part of sample application]

I have imported the [StarterApplication_ionic-release71.zip](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/StarterApplication_ionic?cm_mc_uid=91602315326614437065690&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1444213856) into the existing Eclipse workspace.

In **feeds.html**

```
<button data-ng-click="clickMe()">Click Me!</button>
```

In **controllers.js** in the Scope of **FeedsController**

```
$scope.clickMe = function(){
    alert("123");
    console.log("I am clicked");
};
```

Full code:

```
app.controller('FeedsController', function($rootScope, $scope, feedsService, 
$ionicLoading, $timeout) {
    $scope.clickMe = function(){
        alert("123");
        console.log("I am clicked");
    };
    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({   
        content: '<i class="ion-loading-c"></i> Loading...',
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
    });
    $scope.getFeeds = function() {
        $rootScope.feeds = [];
        $scope.errorMsg = "";
        feedsService().then(function (feeds) {
            $rootScope.feeds = feeds;
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
            $scope.errorMsg = "";
            $scope.loading.hide();
        },
        function(error) {
            $scope.errorMsg = "Could Not Load feeds";
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
            $scope.loading.hide();
        });

    };
    $scope.getFeeds();

});
```

Added the html and js code as mentioned above.

When the button is clicked the clickMe method is fired twice. Which results the alert is prompted twice and log as well.

Tried to figure out the cause with the help of google search and stackoverflow question. But failed to identify what could cause this...

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the sample application and loaded it into Eclipse running MFPF 7.1
Added the code snippets where specified, deployed the application to the server and previewed the Common web resources from the MobileFirst Console (in Chrome stable, latest).

Clicked the "Click Me!" button, and the result was 1 alert and 1 console.log.
Cannot reproduce...

Edit: this is reproduced only in Android, but also outside of the Mobile Browser Simulator (meaning outside of tools provided by IBM MFP).

Comment: As you said, when I tried with common web resources, it is working well. But I was working with mobile browser simulator and getting the above stated issue. Is there any reason for it to behave like this in mobile browser simulator?

Comment: I did not test in the MBS. I will check.

Comment: This does not happen in iOS. This does happen in Android. What is your 7.1 full build number?

Comment: Build number is 7.1.0.00.20150807-0630

Comment: I previewed the Android environment's web resources also outside of the MBS and it is still displaying the alert twice. I suspect that relates to Ionic and not to MFP.

Comment: I tested with Ionic and no MFP at all and couldn't reproduce. @sasi - can you perhaps give us a zip of your common folder to ensure we are testing the right thing?